# VueJS router $routes.push can't push query params

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Why on earth this doesn't work?

```
selectChanged(val) {

        let term_ids = [];
        let taxonomy = '';

        val.forEach((obj) => {
          term_ids.push(obj.term_id);
          taxonomy = obj.taxonomy;
        });

        let obj = this.$route.query;
        obj[taxonomy] = term_ids.join(',');

        this.$router.push({
          query: obj,
        });

      },
```

obj looks like this:

```
{education_levels: "33,36", candidate_countries: "304"}
```

If I hardcode above object it will work as intended, VueJS Router will push query string and it will look like this: `?education_levels=33,36&candidate_countries=304`

But if I pass `query: obj` nothing will happen...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `assign` all the properties with `route`.

`Object.Assign` makes a new COPY of the of the `$route`, including all enumerable OWN properties

One more suggestion -

When you do this  `let obj = this.$route.query;` -
`Objects` get stored to `memory` so when you try to copy an `object` you are actually copying the `address` of the `object` where that stored in memory. 
So when you do this - `obj[taxonomy] = term_ids.join(',');`
You will accidently mutate the original value, so cloning required

Instead clone it-

```
let obj = { ... this.$route.query }
this.$router.push({
   query: Object.assign({}, this.$route.query, obj),
});
```

Comment: Not sure how this can be used in my example. What is a query? obj? Query string?
Tried query: Object.assign({}, this.$route.query, obj), no avail.

Comment: `query` is the `obj`,

Comment: Yes thanks let obj = {}; instead of let obj = this.$route.query; and query: Object.assign({}, this.$route.query, obj), did it.

Comment: happy to help :) Please answer accepted. - https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: What the difference in this situation let obj = { ... this.$route.query } and just let obj = {}?

Comment: Updating answer with some details on this